# Glassfish Eclipse Link JPA Package by feature

Tags: java, jpa, hyperlink, glassfish, eclipselink

I have a j2ee app running but i decided to change the code organization to a package by feature style instead of the package by layer style that i am using now, the main reasons for this change are code navigation and modulatity, i have this schema:

- com.app.domain

  - customer.java
- com.app.dao

  - customerDao.java
  - customerDaoImpl.java
- com.app.service

  - customerService.java
  - customerServiceImpl.java
- com.app.web

  - customerHandler.java

I want to move it to:

- com.app.customer

  - customer.java
  - customerDao.java
  - customerDaoImpl.java
  - customerService.java
  - customerServiceImpl.java
  - customerHandler.java

When i run tests on the new schema everything works fine but when a try to use the customerService via the customerHandler i get this error:

> No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread
>   - cannot reliably process 'persist' call

I tried grouping my classes into the new package one by one to see wich one is the problem, and it is the customerServiceImpl.java, when i move this class outside the com.app.customer package my app works fine, the applicationContext.xml file is configured to scan the com.app.customer package, the customerDaoImpl and customerServiceImpl have @Transactional annotations, i read that either the dao or the service should be transactional but not both, so i tried removing this annotation from either class but i still get the same error.

This is the full stack trace:

```
Warning: StandardWrapperValve[dispatcher]: Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcher threw exception    
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'persist' call
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:278)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy234.merge(Unknown Source)
        at com.app.customer.customerDaoImpl.merge(customerDaoImpl.java:49)
        at com.app.customer.customerServiceImpl.store(customerServiceImpl.java:69)
        at com.app.customer.customerHandler.store(customerHandler.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:817)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:731)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What am i doing wrong? is it possible to build an app using the package by feature style with eclipselink JPA?

By the way i am able to retrieve customer info from the database.

EDIT:

This is the applicationContext.xml file with the orginal packaging style:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">
    <bean id="loadTimeWeaver"  class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.glassfish.GlassFishLoadTimeWeaver" />
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" p:persistenceUnitName="app_PU"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" 
    />
    <tx:jta-transaction-manager />
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <context:annotation-config/> 
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.app.dao"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.app.service"/>
</beans>
```

For the new packaging style i changed this:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.app.dao"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.app.service"/>
```

To this:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.app.customer"/>
```

Then i get the error mentioned above, but if i move the customerServiceImpl.class outside the package com.app.customer to its original location: com.app.service and change the applicationContext.xml to:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.app.customer"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.app.service"/>
```

My app works.

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" 
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence 
                http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="app_PU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/appDB</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="SunAS9"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: I don't think that JPA cares which style of packaging you are using. But the relevant configuration is not posted. So it is difficult to say what is going wrong.

Comment: I just added the applicationContext.xml file, can you please take a look at it and tell me if there is anyting wrong?

Comment: How is your `persistence.xml` configured?

Comment: Added the persistence.xml file

Comment: `persistence.xml` should be OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that when the Controller, Service and DAO classes are in the same package any method call made from the Controller object to the Service object is considered by Spring as a self-invocation call, that's why no transactional behavior was added to the persist, merge or remove methods, it also explains why the app worked when moving either the ServiceImpl or the DaoImpl class to a different package, because thay way any method call is considered as an external call and will be intercepted by the proxy.

The problem was solved by changing the transactional mode to AOP, this [link](http://backcountry.github.io/2015/02/20/Transaction-Management-Modes-with-Spring/) was useful for configuring the new transactional mode.